# val() fails when iterating through a collection of selects (jquery)

Tags: jquery, loops

I've got a form with multiple  elements, and I want to iterate through them, and compare the value of the selected element (in each individual ) with a string. Seems like I would want to use val(), but...

```
$("#FormSection select[class='input-small']").each(function (a, b) {
    if (b.val()!="test") 
                alert('hello');
});
```

In the above, it says that "val" is undefined. But b.id is indeed equal to one of the select elements.

If I alternatively directly use jquery to grab the same select element directly, val() works as expected. So, I compared b from within the loop to the directly grabbed select. And the difference: When directly grabbed, jQuery returned a single-element array. The documentation about val() mentioned that it expects an array, so maybe this is expected.

Interestingly, there's a property "b.value" which has exactly what I expect, but I don't know if it's cross-browser compatible the way jquery methods often are.

I had a really tough time searching for this because my keywords returned results regarding s that allow multiple selection.

Any thoughts would be really appreciated!

Thanks..
-Ben

Comment: Tip: if you don’t care about `a`, you can use `$(this).val()` and not have to define any parameters.

Comment: Tip 2: use more meaningful argument names than `a` and `b` and you're less likely to confuse yourself - the second argument, as explained in [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/each/), is the element itself and _not_ a jQuery object.

Comment: _"The documentation about `val()` mentioned that it expects an array"_ - Well, not really. It can accept an array as an argument, and it can return an array, but it is a method of jQuery objects, not a method of arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap it in `$()` to use `val()`. val() is not a valid method on DOM element but as you mentioned you dont need to do that, instead you could just use `.value` property of the DOM element.

```
$("#FormSection select[class='input-small']").each(function (idx, b) {
    if (b.value !="test") // b represents DOM Element select, $(b) represents jquery object representing DOM element.

    //if(this.value != test) or just use this. this context here is the element of current iteration.
                alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. It doesn't work in older versions of IE. I'm so used to using `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex]` that I kinda forgot that it works elsewhere!

Comment: Thanks PSL, worked like a charm. I decided to avoid using .value directly, just because of what was discussed in this thread. (The possibility that an older browser might not handle it right.)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wrap `b` as a JQuery object, as it's a regular DOM element:

```
if ($(b).val()!="test")
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QexSg/)

Answer (score 1):

For starters your selector should be `"#FormSelection select.input-small"`, but that aside `.each` iterates through each item - in this case, each element of the jQuery object. This means `b` is the `<select>` element itself, and therefore doesn't have jQuery functions.

Try `$(b).val()` instead.

Comment: Much thanks. I've cleaned up my selector per above (same result set), and I now wrap the result as you indicate and it works perfectly. Thanks!